# Is there unique of key hash in android?

Tags: android

In facebook sdk, I must add and save your keyhash into my profile project. When Android project has build release with an keystore, I have a keyhash. My question:
when I build release my project with multiple machines, Have keyhash to change?. Is there unique of keyhash with only one keystore?

Answer (score 1):

No. You can add multiple hash keys in your Facebook Project. When you build release your project with multiple machines, generate hash keys of these machines and add them seperated by comma.

Comment: So, key hash has changed when I build release project on other machines?

Comment: Oh. sorry if you don't understand my question because my english not good. My question: Have keyhash been change when I build release my project on other machines?

Comment: Still no idea what you are asking!! Whichever machine you are using to take release build, generate the hash key of that system and add to Facebook project. Now clear?

Comment: No. I just want to know my keyhash have be change or not when I build release my project on multiple machines?

Answer (score 0):

From your question, key hash of the file will change for each machine. It is unique only for a particular system running Android studio. Whenever you create an build with a different system, the key hash will change.The only solution is, whenever you take new build on the different system, you have to update the new key hash in facebook developer page.

For your 2nd Question, Is there unique of keyhash with only one keystore?

It is not possible to generate Key hash against an Keystore.